# ODE lsqcurvefit with changing ode equations

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, ode

I am trying to fit a curve using a system of ODE's to some data. The system of ODE changes to a different system of ODE depending a predefined time point.

I constructed a simple example below to illustrate.

```
function examplefitting

init = [1];
expdata = [10;40;70;76;80;90;101;110;150;180;200;202;215;240;245]';
time = [5;10;15;20;25;30;35;40;50;55;60;65;70;75;80]';

[x,resnorm] = lsqcurvefit(@data,init,time,expdata);

function z = data(init,time)

alpha = init(1);
y0 = 100;
   tout = [];
   yout = [];
   for i = 2:5
       tvec = [0 15 30 50 65];
       u = [1 0 1 0 1];

       [t y] = ode23s(@Model,[tvec(i-1) tvec(i)],y0,[],alpha,u(i-1));
       nt = length(t);
       tout = [tout;t];
       yout = [yout;y];

       y0 = [y(nt,1)];

   end

z = yout;

function Y = Model(t,y,alpha,u)
if u == 0

Y(1) = y(1).^alpha;

elseif u == 1

Y(1) = alpha*y(1);

end

Y = Y.';
```

You can see that because I have to stop the integrator, and reset it, the lengths of the output, and the lengths of my original data input differ. This causes the error that says "Function value and YDATA sizes are incommensurate." Is there a way that I can extract the best fit alpha, given that it appears in two different systems of ODES which switch depending on the time.

Comment: The function `data` doesn't use the input `time`. Is the idea for the vector `time` passed to `lsqcurvefit` to then be passed to `data` in order to determine the total integration time? Also, it would be helpful if you cleaned up your code to remove all of the superfluous line breaks.

Comment: As written it isn't. I thought that if I let lsqcurvefit fit points only along each tvec(i-1) to tvec(i) then I would get best fit alpha's for each time segment. Instead, I'd like to get the best fit alpha across the whole range of time. I don't think this comment properly addresses your question though?

Comment: To do anything useful I think that you'll need to get your `data` function to at least correspond to the requirements of `lsqcurvefit`. Is that what the question is about? Then `init` and `time` correspond to `X0` and `XDATA`. The output of `data` will need to be the same length as `XDATA`/`time`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not answer yet, but some suggestions.

First, the modern (and faster) way to pass parameters to an integration function is with an anonymous function:

```
[t,y] = ode23s(@(t,y)Model(t,y,alpha,u(i-1)),[tvec(i-1) tvec(i)],y0);
```

Second, you're appending some values twice. Move `tvec` and `u` outside of the `for` loop since they're constant and initialize `tout` and `yout` to the initial time and state

```
tout = tvec(1);
yout = y0;
```

Then, in your loop append new data like this:

```
tout = [tout;t(2:end)];
yout = [yout;y(2:end,:)];
```

Finally, I wonder if you might be able to solve your question by specifying fixed step-size output. You can do this by setting your `tspan` to a vector of more than two elements. Then the integrator will only return points at those specific times.